# 8051 Bubble Sort Issue

Tags: sorting, assembly, 8051

I'm trying to code bubble sort on assembler 8051. This is what I managed to do so far, it sorts in ascending order, but it is also moving the elements leaving a blank space in the first position when it finishes.

looking through the execution step by step I noticed that SUBB isn't changing the value of C making the instruction JC SKIP useless.

```
 DEFSEG     INICIO1,ABSOLUTE
            SEG INICIO1
            JMP INICIO

            ORG 100H
    INICIO: MOV R1,#05H  
    EXT: MOV A,R1
            MOV R2,A
            MOV R0,#30H
            MOV A,@R0
    IN: INC R0
            MOV B,@R0
            CLR C
            SUBB A,B 
            JC SKIP
            MOV B,@R0
            DEC R0
            MOV A,@R0
            MOV @R0,B
            INC R0
            MOV @R0,A
    SKIP: DJNZ R2,IN                
            DJNZ R1,EXT
    STOP: SJMP STOP
            JMP FIN
    FIN:
            END
```

Comment: `SUBB` should be changing the `C` flag, look again.

Answer (score 0):

At `IN` you need `A` equal to `@R0`, but after the jump to `SKIP`, it isn't !

Try:

```
 mov r1, #30h

 mov @r1, #33h
 inc r1
 mov @r1, #44h
 inc r1
 mov @r1, #66h
 inc r1
 mov @r1, #22h
 inc r1
 mov @r1, #11h
 inc r1
 mov @r1, #55h

 mov r3, #5
outer:
 mov a, r3
 mov r2, a
 mov r1, #30h
 mov a, @r1
inner:
 inc r1
 clr c
 subb a, @r1
 mov a, @r1
 jc continue
 dec r1
 xch a, @r1
 inc r1
 mov @r1, a
continue:
 djnz r2, inner
 djnz r3, outer
```

Noting that the initial count (5) is **one less** than the number of items to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

try this subroutine

```
;
;       BUBBLE SORT SUBROUTINE DESCRIPTION            
;          1. PUSH NO. OF ELEMENT                      
;          2. PUSH BASE ADDRESS OF ARRAY               
;                                                      



BUBBLESORT:
    POP 0X7F                      ;RETURN ADDRESS OF SUBROUTINE 
    POP 0X7E      

    POP DPH                       ;BASE ADDRESS OF ARRAY 
    POP DPL   
    POP ACC                       ;COUNTER 

    PUSH 0X7E                     ;PUSH RETURN ADDRESS 
    PUSH 0X7F     

    MOV R0,A                      ;TEMPORARY STORE COUNTER REG.
    MOV R1,A                      ;AND BASE ADDRESS OF ARRAY
    MOV R2,A      
    MOV R3,DPL        
    MOV R4,DPH    

REPEAT_BUBBLESORT:
    MOVX A,@DPTR                  ;MOVE A[I] INTO ACCUMULATOR 
    MOV R5,A                
    
    INC DPTR 
    MOVX A,@DPTR        
    MOV R6,A 

    SUBB A,R5 
    JNC NOTSWAP_BUBBLESORT      ;SWAP IF A[I] > A[I+1]
    MOV A,R6 
    XCH A,R5 
    MOVX @DPTR,A 
    ACALL DEC_DPTR              ;CALL DECREMENT DATA POINTER 
    MOV A,R5 
    MOVX @DPTR,A 
    INC DPTR 
NOTSWAP_BUBBLESORT:             
    DJNZ R2,REPEAT_BUBBLESORT   ;LOWER COUNTER 
    MOV A,R0 
    MOV R2,A 
    MOV DPL,R3                  ;INITILIZE DPTR WITH BASE ADDRESS 
    MOV DPH,R4                  
    DJNZ R1,REPEAT_BUBBLESORT   ;UPPER COUNTER 
    RET                         ;RETURN SUBROUITNE 

                                ;DECREMENT DATA POINTER SUBROUITNE 
DEC_DPTR:
    MOV A,DPL 
    SUBB A,#01 
    JNC SKIP_DEC_DPTR
    MOV A,#0XFF 
    DEC DPH 
SKIP_DEC_DPTR:
    MOV DPL,A 
    RET
```

to store the base address of the array into register before start it initial